# How to get the length of all the drivable or bikeable roads in OSMnx for a chosen city?

Tags: python, openstreetmap, osmnx

I am trying to get the LENGTH of all the drivable streets in Paris, for example. From the documentation, I found this code to get the area of all roads in square meters.

#### What I want to get is the length of all this drivable roads in meters or kilometres. How can I do that?

```
# Get the network graph for drivable public streets (but not service roads)
G = ox.graph_from_place('Paris, France', network_type='drive') # for bikes the network_type would be 'bike'
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G, node_size=0, bgcolor='k')

# what sized area does our network cover in square meters?
G_proj = ox.project_graph(G)
nodes_proj = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G_proj, edges=False)
graph_area_m = nodes_proj.unary_union.convex_hull.area
graph_area_m
```

From the documentation, basic stats show:

```
# show some basic stats about the network
ox.basic_stats(G_proj, area=graph_area_m, clean_intersects=True, circuity_dist='euclidean')
# edge_length_total = sum of all edge lengths in the graph, in meters
# edge_length_avg = mean edge length in the graph, in meters
# street_length_total = sum of all edges in the undirected
# street_length_avg = mean edge length in the undirected
```

#### Is `street_length_total` the length of all the streets in my chosen network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is street_length_total the length of all the streets in my chosen network?

Yes.